# How to get only HTML webpages from Google Custom Search API

Tags: google-custom-search, google-api-python-client, google-apis-explorer

I'm using Google CSE JSON API to obtain some webpages I'll **scrape** later. The thing is sometimes I'm getting PDFs, DOCX and some other files published in the web that I don't want to get from Google.

I know that there is a parameter in this API named as `fileType` that filters the results, but this doesn't work for me because I want the opposite (exclude them not exclude others).

1. I tried using `fileType` telling Google that this is `'html'` but didn't work neither (from results like `example.com/foo` to only `example.net/bar.html`). Using this, for example, any webpage in PHP or ASP won't fit this criteria.
2. I also tried to set `'text/html'` as `fileType` value but it didn't do anything.

The way of filtering it could be the `Content-Type` header included in the response of any HTTP GET petition (`text/html`), but of course it'll be better if Google do this for me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found how to do this easily. Just add the filter to the query `q` parameter in the Google API call using `filetype:foo`. This way you can filter the search to only the results wanted:

```py
service.cse().list(cx=const.SEARCH_ENGINE_KEY, q='"user manual" -filetype:pdf').execute()
```

You can add as many `filetype` filters as you need to get better results.

Now I feel like this was a silly question. Anyway, I hope this help anyone in the future.